# Postgresql: UPSERT / INSERT INTO defining a conflict

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, sql-insert

this is my first post on the platform.

I hope [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfx0Y.png) explains what I am trying to do.
I am trying to merge table B into table A. If the condition is met that (A.cell = B.cell AND A.object = B.objet) then I want to update A.cost with the corresponding cost from table B. If the condition is not met, I want to insert the row from B into A.

What I have tried so far is an upsert, but it didn't work:

```
INSERT INTO reached_points
SELECT B.cell_id, B.object_id, B.reached_cost
FROM test_reached_cells B
ON CONFLICT (cell_id, object_id)
WHERE (cell_id = B.cell_id AND object_id = B.object_id)
DO UPDATE SET cost = B.reached_cost
```

I thought in the WHERE clause after the CONFLICT I could define when that conflict is 'triggered'. Is this not the case? I thought so because in the [documentation](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/) it says something like "[ON CONFLICT target action;] The target can be:  WHERE predicate – a WHERE clause with a predicate".

Is there a way to achieve an update and if the condition is not met, an insert? I wanted to avoid to do it in two completely seperate steps, because it seems inefficient to compare the tables twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought in the WHERE clause after the CONFLICT I could define when that conflict is 'triggered'. Is this not the case?

No. What defines the concflict is the *target*, the expression that immediatly follows the `ON CONFLICT` keyword. In your query, that is:

```
on conflict(cell_id, object_id)
```

...which is what you want - note that this require that you have a unique index on this tuple of column (or a primary key constraint). So you don't need (nor want) this `where` clause.

Also, to access the column from the other table in the `do update` clause, you can use pseudo-table `excluded`.

Consider:

```
insert into reached_points(cell_id, object_id, cost)
select cell_id, object_id, reached_cost from test_reached_cells
on conflict(cell_id, object_id)
do update set cost = excluded.cost
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=31186f5f42d2a9156a530e6b4d3769a3)**:

Sample data:

```
select * from reached_points;
```

```
cell_id | object_id | cost
------: | --------: | ---:
      1 |         2 |    3
```

```
select * from test_reached_cells;
```

```
cell_id | object_id | reached_cost
------: | --------: | -----------:
      1 |         2 |            4
      1 |         3 |            4
```

Query:

```
insert into reached_points(cell_id, object_id, cost)
select cell_id, object_id, reached_cost from test_reached_cells
on conflict(cell_id, object_id)
do update set cost = excluded.cost
-- 2 rows affected
```

Results:

```
select * from reached_points;
```

```
cell_id | object_id | cost
------: | --------: | ---:
      1 |         2 |    4
      1 |         3 |    4
```